# layout-small not being recognized/not working

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I made a layout-small xml file to fit smaller screen sizes for my activity. I was told that if you create a folder, named `layout-small`(with the XML inside it, of course) inside the `res` folder, android would recognize that the phones screen size is `small` and would automatically use the `layout-small` XML file.

I used the 3.2" HVGA Slider AVD to test the program, but it still used the normal layout. I hope this make sense, as I couldn't find another question similar to this.

If you need any additonal information or have any questions, let me know.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this page](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/tools/revisions/platforms.html) your AVD device has a screen size of "normal", so you will not pick up the definition for "small".

> **Device Definitions**
>
> The platform includes the following device definitions for use in creating Android Virtual Devices in the AVD Manager:
>
> ...
>
> • 3.2" HVGA slider ADP1 (320 x 480, Normal mdpi screen)

If you want to target your AVD with a different layout, take a look at ways to [specify an alternative](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html).